# NHibernate: many-to-many mapping exception

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have a c# .net 3.5 application using NHibernate and MySQL.

My SQL tables are laid out in a many-to-many pattern linking configuration strings to tasks

```
CREATE TABLE `configstring` (
  `ConfigStringID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ConfigString` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ConfigStringID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `task_configstring` (
  `ConfigStringID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TaskID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ConfigStringID`,`TaskID`),
  KEY `TaskID` (`TaskID`),
  KEY `ConfigStringID` (`ConfigStringID`),
  CONSTRAINT `ConfigStringID` FOREIGN KEY (`ConfigStringID`) REFERENCES `configstring` (`ConfigStringID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `TaskID` FOREIGN KEY (`TaskID`) REFERENCES `task` (`TaskID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `TaskID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TaskID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have a `Task` class that contains a list of configuration strings like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public virtual IList<string> ConfigurationStrings { get; set; }
}
```

The NHibernate XML mapping for this class to the database looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="QueueTest"
                   namespace="Phoenix.Action">

    <class name="Task" table="queue_task">
        <id name="Id" column="TaskID" type="int" >
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <bag name="ConfigurationStrings" table="queue_task_configstring">
            <key column="TaskID"/>

            <many-to-many column="ConfigStringID"/>

        </bag>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

But, when I call `Configuration().BuildSessionFactory()`, I get this exception: `An association from the table task_configstring does not specify the referenced entity`

What's the correct way to do a many-to-many mapping to a `System.String` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a class for the ConfigString ?

You're missing the class name in the many-to-many mapping.

Create a new ConfigString entity:

```
class ConfigStringEntity
{
   public virtual int ConfigStringID { get; set; }

   public virtual string ConfigString { get; set; }
}

<many-to-many class="ConfigStringEntity" column="ConfigStringID"/>
```

Your list will then be a list of ConfigStringEntity.

```
public class Task
{
    public virtual IList<ConfigStringEntity> ConfigurationStrings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The class is a System.String. I just want the string from the `ConfigString` column

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you still need an entity for the ConfigString, which you'll then use in the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: It seems wrong to have to create a class to wrap a string so it fits the database convention of having an ID. What about using a `formula` in the `many-to-many` tag? Is there some SQL SELECT statement I can do to just return the string?

Comment: Alternately, is there a way to create the xml for a persistent class, but not create the class in c#?

Comment: I agree that it seems overkill, but I'm not sure if there's an alternative. I searched around, and the only article that mentioned formulas in a many-to-many mapping dated back to 2006, and it mentionned that it wasn't supported. I did stumble upon this article for Hibernate, and its supported for them... Maybe they ported it over since then: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html#example-mappings-composite-key-manytomany